# Split a log file using preg_split based on dates with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, logging, preg-split

I have a txt file with this format:

```
14/12/2020 12:02:50
LOG_HERE_1 XXXXX

14/12/2020 12:04:55
LOG_HERE_2 XXXXX

14/12/2020 12:10:33
LOG_HERE_3 XXXXX
```

And I need to parse it, using a regexp on the dates (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss), but keeping the date on the array.
For example:

```
Array(
 [0] => '14/12/2020 12:02:50 LOG_HERE_1 XXXXX',
 [1] => '14/12/2020 12:02:50 LOG_HERE_2 XXXXX',
 [2] => '14/12/2020 12:02:50 LOG_HERE_3 XXXXX'
)
```

I tried this:

```php
$array = preg_split('/(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s\d{2}[:]\d{2}[:]\d{2})/', $data, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

but it shows me:

```
{
 0: "",
 1: "14/12/2020 12:02:50",
 2: "",
 3: "14/12/2020 12:04:55",
 4: "",
 5: "14/12/2020 12:10:33",
 6: ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the flag `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` you can also match the lines that start with a date time like format followed by all lines that do not start with one using a negative lookahead `(?!`

```
^(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\h\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\b.*\R(?:(?!\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\h\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\b).*\R?)*)
```

If starting with a date like pattern would also suffice, you could shorten it to:

```
^(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\b.*\R(?:(?!\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\b).*\R?)*)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sInfpP/1)

For example

```
$pattern = "~^(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\h\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\b.*\R(?:(?!\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\h\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\b).*\R?)*)~m";    
$result = preg_split($pattern, $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($result);
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/uLqp4) or with the [log on the same line](https://3v4l.org/fllBO).

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 14/12/2020 12:02:50
LOG_HERE_1 XXXXX


    [1] => 14/12/2020 12:04:55
LOG_HERE_2 XXXXX


    [2] => 14/12/2020 12:10:33
LOG_HERE_3 XXXXX
)
```

**Note** that the date like pattern does not validate a date itself.

Comment: I tried this solution, , but the lines behind the date, does not show, it returns me just the dates without logs text

Comment: @NicolasManzanos Is the structure of the example log the same as the real log? Are there spaces before the date? https://regex101.com/r/238aVg/1 Are you reading the whole file at once? What is the output of `var_dump($data);` ?

Comment: I noticed that the dates in my log had a tabulation instead of space in the middle, now its fixed!, thanks you